# Change class on tr element after action on tr

Tags: ember.js

With Ember 2.0 coming down the pipeline and the move away from itemControllers & views, what is the best way to apply the selected class to the currently selected `tr` element?

Originally there was just the each loop within the controller template that set itemControllers on each `tr` element. The itemController would then hold the `isSelected` property as well as hoisting it into the `parentController` upon select.

Selection currently is working without issues with the bindings of `pumpSelected` to a property passed into the component.

Although the code is a bit cleaner after the refactor, it's just pushed the need for the itemController lower to me.  Any help appreciated.

Component .hbs snippet:

```
{{#each pump in results}}
  <tr {{action 'select' pump}} {{bind-attr class='isSelected:selected'}}>
    <td>{{pump.modelNumber}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Component Definition:

```
PumpResultComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  tagName: 'table'
  classNames: ['table', 'table-striped']

  actions:
    select: (selectedPump)->
      @set 'pumpSelected', selectedPump
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'm doing this right now is by wrapping the content in a list and defining the selected state in each item. In your template you can than loop over this wrapper list, so in your case:

```
PumpResultComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    pumpList: function() {
        var selected = this.get('pumpSelected');
        return this.get('results').map(function(pump) {
            return {
                isSelected: selected && pump.get('id') === selected.get('id'), // or some other equality property 
                pump: pump
            };
        });
    }.property('pumpSelected','results')
});

{{#each item in pumpList}}
    <tr {{action 'select' item.pump}} {{bind-attr class='item.isSelected:selected'}}>
        <td>{{item.pump.modelNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I did find a [thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-a-good-way-to-do-this-in-ember-2-0-no-itemcontroller-no-arraycontroller/66490) that discusses things very similar to this after posting.  Seems obvious after looking >.< -- Thanks for a great answer.